# Query Issue with exists subquery

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am very new to the SForce apex coding and am trying to get my head around subqueries using an exists statement.

I am trying to get the Accounts that are linked to a custom object via a customer property on the standard account object. Here is what i am trying:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Customer_ID__c 
FROM Account
where lastName = 'TestCustomer' AND exists (SELECT Id 
                                           FROM Duplicate_ID__c 
                                           WHERE Duplicate_ID__c = Customer_ID__c)
LIMIT 100
```

Here is error i am getting:
ERROR at Row:3Column:44
unexpectd token:'select'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `exists` clause in SOQL. Try following query:

```
SELECT 
     Id, FirstName, LastName, Customer_ID__c 
FROM Account 
WHERE 
    lastName = 'TestCustomer' 
AND 
    Customer_ID__c IN (select Duplicate_ID__c from Duplicate_ID__c)
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I get a MALFORMED_QUERY - semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot us: 'Duplicate_ID__c'. If i understand this it means that the id of the custom object is the only thing i can select on. Can i get around this?

Comment: You are correct in understanding what it means... Unfortunately, I can't think of an efficient way to get around this without changing data model. You are more likely to get help on this if you could describe your use case in more details. Personally I'm interested in `Duplicate_ID__c` object - why do you need it, how and when do you populate it?

Comment: Is Duplicate_ID__c the name of the object AND the name of the field on the same object?